# getting the query result in json format when working with sforce.connection.query

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I have this javascript code in a VF page where I'm trying to fetch records from the DB.
I'm getting back an xml format but I need it as a json format.
Is there a way to get the result records in json or do some kind of conver?

```
    var result = sforce.connection.query(query);
    var records = result.getArray("records");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use json.stringify to convert the array of records into json as shown below

```
var result = sforce.connection.query(query); 
var records = result.getArray("records"); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(records));
```

This is the output I get

[image]